# How to fetch some content from a url and put it on an input box in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have got my website at this link: [www.website.zzz](http://www.website.zzz) , Sometimes my website is loaded from different links (maybe I should say dynamic) for example [www.website.zzz/?ref=name1](http://www.website.zzz/?ref=name1), [www.website.zzz/?ref=name2](http://www.website.zzz/?ref=name2), [www.website.zzz/?ref=name3](http://www.website.zzz/?ref=name3), As i can say the key value on these three examples is 'ref' which takes different names, as name1, name2, name3, and more. When this link is clicked it goes direct to the signup form, on the sign up form i have got two input fields as which takes email and content from a url used. I want this box which takes content to take the name from the url, for example if someone uses this link: [www.website.zzz/?ref=name4](http://www.website.zzz/?ref=name4), this input 4 will get this content 'name4' such that when the user goes on to submit the form this name will be submited also. I have no any hint, that why i did not include any content. I need an example of html code which does this.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="param">Parameter: </label>
      <input id="param"/>
    </form>
    <script>
      (function(){
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const ref = urlParams.get('ref')
        document.getElementById('param').value = ref;
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is it. Yes its actually working, however when I looad the page all my css styles is gone. All image on my page are nolonger showing. What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

- Read the query string using [window.location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search)
- Set an `<input>` value using [HTMLInputElement.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)